# Flutter canvas.drawline border radius

Tags: flutter, canvas

Is it possible to give the border radius of Flutter canvas.drawline?

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.red;
    paint.strokeWidth = 10;
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(0, 0), new Offset(size.width, size.height), paint,);
    canvas.drawLine(new Offset(size.width, 0), new Offset(0, size.height), paint,);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution,

```
 paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation than a single line of code. Explaining the code as part of the answer is a good practice. Please read more about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)